# Can I call GetThreadTimes() from within the thread?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, performance

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
HANDLE myHandle = GetCurrentThread();
GetThreadTimes(myHandle,lpCreationTime,lpExitTime,lpKernelTime,lpUserTime);
```

However, this appears to result in the thread crashing.
Is it possible to call `GetThreadTimes()` from within the thread whose time you want to measure?

EDIT: The system error code I get by calling GetLastError() after the crash is error 183 (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course that's possible. In fact any (ever invalid) thread handle value shall not lead to crash. The root cause may be invalid pointers `lpCreationTime`, `lpExitTime`, `lpKernelTime`, `lpUserTime` that you passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks. The root cause was unallocated pointers.